# WordPress wp_mail function not working, returns false

Tags: wp-mail

I am sending email with the `wp_mail()` function but it is not working. It is returning false. Also it is not giving any error in the server log.

This is my code:

```
         $mailResult = false;
         $to = "tayyabvohra@gmail.com";
         $subject = "HUDPowerBid Mailgun Test exec on ";
         $message = "Testing Mailgun at: ";
         $mailResult = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers);
         $myarr= array('error' => true, 'mail' => $mailResult);
```

**I have also tried with the above code and below code also I have tried with these two codes at once but nothing is working**

```
    $to1 = 'abc@gmail.com';
    $subject1 = 'Post Published by Author';
    $headers1 = 'From: admin <admin@urdutahzeeb.com>' . "\r\n";  
    $message1 = 'your';

        $a=wp_mail($to1, $subject1, $message1, $headers1);
        $my=array('checkstatus'=>$a,'second'=>$mailResult);
        echo json_encode($my);
```

Comment: Have you tried PHP mail with the same headers? Perhaps your mail host has some limitations on what you can do.

Comment: remove ."\r\n" from $headers1.

Answer (score 3):

Although `wp_mail` returns false on failure, it does also contain an action hook to allow you access to error information.

If `phpmailer` fails to send, these lines run:

```
 /**
         * Fires after a phpmailerException is caught.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param WP_Error $error A WP_Error object with the phpmailerException message, and an array
         *                        containing the mail recipient, subject, message, headers, and attachments.
         */
        do_action( 'wp_mail_failed', new WP_Error( 'wp_mail_failed', $e->getMessage(), $mail_error_data ) );

        return false;
```

If you attach a function to `wp_mail_failed` you can look at the `WP_Error` object to get more info on your problem.

Comment: @butlerblog Thanks for your edit, but my use of the word "does" is deliberate emphasis so I've rolled it back.